# How do I modify the contents of an XElement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

is there a simple way to modify the InnerXml of a XElement?
supose we have this extremely simple xml

```
<planets>
    <earth></earth>
    <mercurio></mercurio>
</planets>
```

and we want to append some xml that come from another source that comes like a string "`<continents><america/><europa/>.....blablabla`" into the earth node.

I read related questions but they talk about retrieving the innerxml of a XElement and i don't understand how "modify" the actual Xelement :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Build the XML**

```
planetsElement.Element("earth").Add(
    new XElement("continents",
        new XElement("america"),
        new XElement("europa")
    )   
);
```

**Parse and Add**

```
planetsElement.Element("earth").Add(
   XElement.Parse("<continents><america/><europa/></continents>")
);
```

Comment: The source is a string, supposed we have a string with thousand of nodes, this aproach isn't useful. The XmlElement have the innerXml property and only a assignation is need it. My cuestion target if there is a simple way like that.

Comment: ou ok Chaos i didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

Use `XElement.ReplaceNodes()` to set the content of your Element. So ...

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var earth = doc.Root.Element("earth");

// to replace the nodes use
earth.ReplaceNodes(XElement.Parse("<continents><america/><europa/></continents>"));

// to add the nodes
earth.Add(XElement.Parse("<continents><america/><europa/></continents>"));
```